# Ctrl+Shift+V doesn't paste to terminal now?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I am used to copy and pasting into the terminal and out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. But on raring, this key command seems to not work? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does copy though.

How can I fix the terminal to have the old key bindings?

Comment: I've just tested this on my 13.04 machine.  It works as expected.

Comment: I always use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for pasting in a terminal.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a different keybinding conflicting with this one?

Comment: It works fine when im going from the terminal to the terminal, but fails when I copy something from outside the terminal and try to past it into the terminal.

Comment: I checked the key bindings too. @Seth. Its one of those things where i can get around it, but its obnoxious too. So today, I encountered it and posted. Are there and left / right specifications to key bindings? I use left shift and left control to do these commands.

Comment: You say "...  fails when I copy something from outside the terminal"  Is this anything outside the terminal or just one particular application?

Comment: @j0h I think there are, but I don't think it should matter. I use the left ones too and it works just fine. Have you installed anything recently? Or have you tinkered with any key bindings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to edit your keyboard shortcuts:

- Open a terminal
- Click `edit` in the menu bar
- Click `Keyboard shortcuts` in the menu

I hope this helps

Comment: certainly good to know, but the key binding is ctrl+shift+V for paste.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem in 15.04. Solved it by:

- Open a terminal
- Click `Edit` in the menu bar
- Click `Preferences`
- Click `Keyboard shortcuts`
- Check "`Enable keyboard shortcuts`"

Now shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> work as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04.5. I was able to get it to work by using "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "V to" paste and then right-clicking on the line in the terminal with my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on some terminals (when the keyboard language is different from system language).

On these terminals I have verified that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes the contents of the clipboard if I lift my finger from the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (while holding down the other two keys). The procedure for copying is similar.

It's strange and not very functional but it works.